# replacement of eureka client and server in spring boot version 3.1.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

https://start.spring.io/

I tried to add eureka server and eureka client from spring initializr , is eureka server and client is deprecated , and what will be the alternatives of eureka . will eureka come with updated version or i should search another alternatives , please suggest if have any suggession .

Answer (score 0):

**apache zookeeper discovery** & **consul discovery**
Both work fine with spring boot 3.1.0 but Eureka was something else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).